# How to remote access a HDD-locked (node-locked) license?

Tags: windows-7, networking, license, remote-control

I have a software license that is locked to my HDD at work (unfortunately...). During the break I want to do some work from home, but I cannot debug without the license.

I am thinking of connecting to my work computer somehow to use this license, but I don't really know how. This computer is on the university network, so I cannot configure the router.

It looks like Windows Remote Desktop requires router configuration, so that's kind of out the question. I can run VPN to get into the University network from home, but I don't know how to access individual computers then. I can access my shared account using WinSCP (FTP I guess), but not the hard drive I'm interested in.

Is there a way to do this? Short of ripping the hard drive out and taking it with me for the holidays...

I have Windows 7 Enterprise (and Ubuntu 14.04) at work. At home I have Windows 7 (Professional?). For the record, the software in question is Xilinx's ChipScope.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Chrome browser has an addon for remote access.  There are a bunch of others that don't require router configuration, but still depend on fairly unrestricted access to the PC you want to connect to.  Can you install what you like?

Comment: What do you mean by HDD locked anyway?  If the hard disk crashed, and you installed a new one, what is the procedure for getting the app up and running after restoring from backup?

Comment: If the HDD crashed, I have to manually migrate the license to a different host using the License Manager for the software. I only get 3 of these migrations. HDD-locked means it has my HDD's serial number in the license file. And yep, I can install anything, I'm an admin on this computer. I'll go check out those Chrome addons.

Comment: @Paul, I installed Chrome Remote Desktop and that's amazing! I am actually running the IDE from my phone, which is so so so cool. :D Thank you! If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main types of remote access approaches.

One is the traditional Remote Desktop type approach such as is used by Microsoft or even standard ssh, which requires permitting an incoming connection, and so require the perimeter router/firewall to be configured to allow the incoming connection.  The constraint of this is that access to the router is required.

The second is where the system being accessed makes an outbound connection to another server outside of the controlled network, and it is via that outbound connection that an incoming connection is made.

A basic example of this could be made with ssh.  The internal, inaccessible host creates an outgoing ssh connection to an accessible server, and creates a [reverse tunnel](http://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling).  This effectively creates a port on the accessible server that acts as a tunnel back to the inaccessible host.  This command is executed on the internal machine:

```
ssh -R 33389:internalip:3389 remote@remoteserver
```

This creates port 33389 on remote server that connects to 3389 to the internal host at `internalip`.

ssh would need to be permitted outbound for this to succeed.

Other options used http as a transport, and use a central registration service.  The internal host registers with the central service, and that outgoing link to the central service allows the incoming connection back into the internal host.

There are several services out there for this, look for those that provide [NAT passthrough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software#Features)